# Как импортировать компонент?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

хотел добавить себе компонент vue-pincode-input, установил его через терминал, посмотрел нотацию об этом, сильно не понял как импортировать, когда начинаю его использовать компонент в штмл, то ошибка ссылается на первую строчку, как это исправить ?

```js
import PincodeInput from 'vue-pincode-input';
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   components: {
      PincodeInput,
   },
   data() {
      return {
         code: null
      }
   },
   methods: {

   },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы не используете к-л сборщик (например, [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) или [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/)), то путь в импорте `"vue-pincode-input"` не валиден.

Чтобы использовать ES6 импорты, нужно:

- Чтобы тег `<script>`, в котором ваш код находится, имел аттрибут `type="module"`
- В самом импорте путь должен быть полный и относительный (пример с npm: `"./node_modules/vue-pincode-input/index.js"`)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно установить vue c использование npm https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/installation.html#npm